# File is not created in Docker

Tags: bash, docker

I am new to Docker and trying to build Docker image. I simply created Docker file but getting some error not able to identify how to resolve this.

My Docker file code is:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER  ravat  
RUN echo “Hello Apache server on Ubuntu Docker” > /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/index.html
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

the error I am getting is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/index.html: Directory nonexistent
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Docker image is essentially a virtual machine that runs alongside (or within) your desktop OS. However, it does not have the same file structure - it probably does not even have a `ravata` user, nevermind all the other path folders you've specified. If you are building a web app, then you will probably want to redirect to `/var/www/index.html`, depending on where your Docker app web server will serve it from.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why are you trying to create the file at this specific location, but as error hints you, you need to create a folder you'd like to put your file first, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER  ravat

RUN mkdir -p /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/
RUN echo “Hello Apache server on Ubuntu Docker” > /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/index.html
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Just to make it clear, the reason you do not have home folder for username ravata is the fact that no such user exists on brand new ubuntu docker image.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you why, `/home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/` directory doesn't exists.

You should first create it.

Note that this file will be created inside your container, not on your computer. So directory should be created inside the container, for example with a `RUN mkdir ...`

Comment: can you please help me out where the container and Image is located.

Comment: The container's filesystem is located by default at `/var/lib/docker/aufs`, but you should not have to change this. Instead, create the directory with a `RUN mkdir -p /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/` inside your Dockerfile